# make combinations of two array in json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, recursion, lodash

Input :

```
"options": [
  {
    "name": "Color",
    "values": [
      "Blue",
      "Black"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Size",
    "values": [
      "Small",
      "Large"
    ]
  }
]

Output: "variants": [
  {
    "option1": "Blue",
    "option2": "Small"
  },
  {
    "option1": "Blue",
    "option2": "Large"
  },
  {
    "option1": "Black",
    "option2": "Small"
  },
  {
    "option1": "Black",
    "option2": "Large"
  }
]
```

How to solve this using recursion ?The options array can contain multiple name and i need the above out to be displayed. Can it be done using cartesian product i guess

Comment: *The options array can contain multiple name* how is this relevant? Since you lose the `name` in your output anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an iterative and recursive approach for getting all option combinations.

```js
function getCombinations(array) {

    function iter(i, temp) {
        if (i === array.length) {
            result.push(temp.reduce(function (o, v, i) {
                o['option' + (i + 1)] = v;
                return o;
            }, {}));
            return;
        }
        array[i].values.forEach(function (a) {
            iter(i + 1, temp.concat(a));
        });
    }

    var result = [];
    iter(0, []);
    return result;
}

var options = [{ name: "Color", values: ["Blue", "Black"] }, { name: "Size", values: ["155", "159"] }, { name: 'Material', values: ['Sand', 'Clay', 'Mud'] }],
    variants = getCombinations(options);

console.log(variants);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6

```js
function getCombinations(array) {

    function iter(i, temp) {
        if (i === array.length) {
            result.push(temp);
            return;
        }
        array[i].values.forEach(a => iter(i + 1, Object.assign({}, temp, { ['option' + (i + 1)]: a })));
    }

    var result = [];
    iter(0, {});
    return result;
}

var options = [{ name: "Color", values: ["Blue", "Black"] }, { name: "Size", values: ["155", "159"] }, { name: 'Material', values: ['Sand', 'Clay', 'Mud'] }],
    variants = getCombinations(options);

console.log(variants);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: its doesn't work for situations :[{ name: "Color", values: ["Blue", "Black"] }, { name: "Size", values: ["small"] }, { name: "Material", values: [] }]   ... Blue,Small is created but no Black,Small combination  ..Actually the elements of the values array comes dynamically .. and it can be of any number even empty ...

Comment: and what result do you expect? please add a complete `options` as well.

Comment: the output should be : Blue-Small and Black Small .. m making variants for products `options= [{ name: "Color", values: ["Blue", "Black"] }, { name: "Size", values: ["Small"] },{ name: "Material", values: [] }]` ... `options= [{ name: "Color", values: ["Blue", "Black"] }, { name: "Size", values: [] },{ name: "Material", values: ["Cotton"] }]`.. these are some situations

Comment: if that is the case, the original should return four combinations instead of two?

Comment: that changes all. you want to get a cross product of all items.

Comment: yup .. need all the possible combinations ... any help ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163890/discussion-between-infinitywarior-and-nina-scholz).

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) calls, create the objects, and flatten the sub arrays using [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
const options = [{"name":"Color","values":["Blue","Black"]},{"name":"Size","values":["155","159"]}]

const [{ values: colors }, { values: sizes }] = options
const result = [].concat(...colors.map((option1) => sizes.map((option2) => ({
  option1,
  option2
}))))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: How does second line work? It is destructuring assignment  but seems weird.

Comment: It's object destrucutring ({}) inside array destructuring ([]).

Comment: So basically you are assigning to a new variable because the first one already use that name? Could be like var [{ values: colors }, { values:sizes }] = options  too?

Comment: Indeed - I'm [assigning to new variable names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names), and indeed I can name the 2nd one sizes. I've updated the example.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myarray = {"options": [
  {
    "name": "Color",
    "values": [
      "Blue",
      "Black"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Size",
    "values": [
      "155",
      "159"
    ]
  }
]};

const key = myarray.options[0].values;
const value =myarray.options[1].values;
const output = _.zipWith(key, value, (key, value)=> ({ key, value }));
console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.6/lodash.min.js"></script>
```